# Site/XAMPP crashing

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have had been running a php based site on a hosting before , then my host has expired now I moved it to my localhost using xampp on my Ubuntu machine , the site has had over 50,000 (Fifty Thousand) records which are meant to be displayed on pages.
Whenever I try to open the site on localhost , it loads half way keeps loading and loading and nothing happens till my apache or browser crashes.

Storage engine of my Database is MyISAM, and its size is almost 443 MB.

I was wondering what can be done , in order to use the site properly without any crashes and what needs to be done?

Comment: What are the errors in the server logs?

Comment: @Jocelyn no major/minor errors.